# Finding data relations or graphs in many-to-many SQL tables

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, data-mining, graph-databases

I have several types of many-has-many tables in my work. I have apps that relate words to other words (ngrams), and databases that could relate users to other users (friends/followers).

**I would like to know how I can build relations with this data to find useful connections for both my application recommendations and for my users.**

Take the following simplistic database table with a foreign key linking a node to another node.

```
id | node1  | node2 
--------------------
1  |   1    |   2
2  |   1    |   3
3  |   1    |   4
4  |   2    |   1
5  |   2    |   3
6  |   2    |   5
7  |   3    |   1
```

For example, in the table above it might be obvious that "1" is the most popular since it's being linked to the most (by 2 & 3). It might also be apparent that perhaps "2" should be linked to "4" since "2" shares so many relations to "1" (and "1" is linked to "4").

So, for example I could find:

- paths that connect nodes to other nodes.
- beneficial connections based on similarities (recommendations)
- groups of nodes that share related connections

Other common forms of relations are things like `user <=> friends` or  `blog_post <=> tags`.

**I'm looking for SQL queries that can be run directly by the front end, or map-reduce jobs that can be run each night to pull relationships from this data.**

Comment: Your relation graph is already built - your nodes form a kind of adjacency lists with repetitions (i.e. list of edges). You can find path from one node to another with algorithms like BFS. Groups of nodes are easy to find with normal SQL and `GROUP BY` operation. And for searching similarities/recommendations you need a particular algorithm (e.g. [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering)). Anyway, you already have relations, so please refine your question to illustrate your actual purpose.

Comment: What is Id? a surrogate key? does a tuple intend to mean: "node2 likes node1" ?

Comment: As wildplasser said you need to figure out your algorithm and then write the Sql. I would change the question to "what is the preferred recommendation algorithm"

Answer (score 1):

As ffriend points out, your data structure is good for what you are trying to do.  This is more of a front end question, as in, how are you going to present the information?

Something to look into is some node traversing techniques to determine number of hops between nodes (relavancy), the number of nodes connect to a single node (breadth), how many hops a meaningful path could take (depth).  The only other thing I would consider is usage to help determine relavancy.  This would more or less be a counter in how many times the node path has been traveled during usage. This is where you can start asigning a weight for a particular path.  For example, if the path from 1 to 5 (1 -> 2 -> 5) is traveled as the first traversal, it might look something like this...

```
id | node1  | node2  | count
------------------------------
1  |   1    |   2    |   1
2  |   1    |   3    |   0
3  |   1    |   4    |   0
4  |   2    |   1    |   0
5  |   2    |   3    |   0
6  |   2    |   5    |   1
7  |   3    |   1    |   0
```

**This method could help to identify meaning relationships between nodes by using a counter as a weight factor.**

Keep in mind that with this kind of data structure, you will need a method to go each direction (1 -> 5, and 5 -> 1)

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember about graphs, Dijkstra-Prinn and Kruskal's algorithms may be of use to you here. They are both searching algorithms (I can't remember if they're BFS or DFS...its been a while :p) that will help you take an entire graph and find optimal traversal paths.

They won't get you the SQL query, but they will provide a mathematical "diving board" to help you get the logic right for your SQL queries.

As hydroparadise stated with his counter system, you could utilize the above stated procedures to get a starting point, then use the counter system to double check it.

Also, as ffriend stated previously, I'm not sure if you're collecting this data for optimization purposes or for some other use, so I think if you restructure your question, you may get better help.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

maybe looking for a NOSQL db would be a better way to solve you're problem. to be more specific, use some graph db like neo4j to represent your sql data first, and than simply traverse the graph to find relations and groups you want to.

in your use case it will be always better to use a graph db, since the performance is several times faster than when using sql with multiple joins on tables.